# Using tags inside a step definition but not in the step

Tags: ruby, cucumber

This question pertains to Cucumber:

I've a need to use a special tag within the step_definition so that from my library of step_definitions, I can quickly search. But, the same tag should not be required in the actual step inside the feature file.

**Example:**

(a) step_definition looks like:

```
Given(/^sys: I execute "(.*?)" command$/)
```

(b) The step in the feature file should look like:

```
Given I execute "hostname" command
```

**Note:** There is no use of the tag (sys:) in the step.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the tag:

- A non-capturing group (the ?:)
- That is expected to match exactly 0 times (the {0}?)

The step definition would look like:

```
Given /^(?:sys: ){0}?I execute "(.*?)" command$/ do |command|
  p command #=> "hostname"
end
```